# Maven build - include classes in projects /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes

Tags: maven

We have to build ontop of an application that we did not develop and we need to include some classes from the Jar's WEB-INF directory. How do we get maven to do this? The eclipse deployment directory includes this for local deploy but the built war looks different and does not include the files we place in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dependency plugin unpack dependency option to unpack from a dependency and output it to a location you desired.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html

Or alternatively, you can use the maven assembly plugin's unpack describtor to achieve the same thing.